# Web API project is not working locally when using port 443 for HTTPS endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, https, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a Web api project with target framework .net 6.0. I'm using Kestrel server to run the project locally using visual studio 2022. App runs smoothly when I use any port number other than 443 for the HTTPS url. If I use 443 for the HTTPS, app is not running(swagger page is not loading). Any hint why HTTPS url is not working with 443?

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:443"
      },
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:8080"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/determine-which-program-use-block-tcp-ports (or similar) and [edit] the question with details of what uses 443 port on your machine or confirm that nothing does (potentially just delete the question if that is the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@Alexei Levenkov** pointed out correctly, There is a system process with PID 4 was already using the port 443. I was able to run the service successfully when using a different port other than 443.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting errors launching the Kestrel server with `dotnet run` command when trying to use ports 80/443. The cause for me was that IIS Sites with bindings on these ports were running (with application pools stopped) and that was causing there to be a process running that locked these ports. Stopping all IIS Sites with bindings for 80 or 443 freed up the ports and allowed me to run the site in Kestrel with `dotnet run`

Answer (score 0):

port 443 is the default to do by connecting https, so it's good that other apps from your local machine through this port you may have problems uploading something to it, also  **a possibility that this port you're traveling with problems is closed for some diagnostic reason To do this, do the following**

Step 1

open your cmd

step 2

Type "telnet microsoft.com 443"

**If the following is closed**

1 - Open as Windows settings, you can use the shortcut "Windows key + I".

2 - Click update and security

3 - Click Firewall and Network Protection.

4 - Click on Advanced Settings

5 - In the left pane click Inbound Rules

6 - In the right pane click on New Rule

7 - Select the Rule Type option.

8 - Select Port.

9 - Click here

10 - Select the appropriate TCP protocol

11 - In the Specific Local Ports field, type 443